# ASP.NET MVC Missing Default Action only for one controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I don't know what happened to my website. From today the default action "Index" in only one controller doesn't work anymore. 
If I call http://website.com/Valuation i get 403 error page because the webserver doesn't route my request and try to browse the folder. If I write http://website.com/Valuation/Index everything works.
I search in all the code but i can't find the problem, everything seems fine like other controllers.

How can i find the problem? Do you know if there are a known issue that cause that problem or you know if there is a trace\log\debugger of routing requests?

Thanks

Mic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably the issue is you have a folder by name **Valuation** in your **website root**. Thats why the valuation index action is not working. Instead of routing to the Controller Action the url http://website.com/Valuation is routing to the Folder **Valuation**.

Delete this folder **Valuation** from your root or rename it then this url http://website.com/Valuation  will work.

Also check if the  ValuationController has the public ActionResult Index() ([HttpGet] method.

Comment: Thanks you save my day! it's a folder created by a batch program in the wrong place... now everything works! Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me, I have no idea how that directory got there

Answer (score 0):

Check ~\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs file

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have exactly this code in my RouteConfig indeed everything in my website is routed correctly excepts just one specific controller. Few days ago was ok also this controller but now simply doesn't work anymore. Probably i have an issue in my code buy i can't find it. I need a method to troubleshoting more than a solution to fix it